# "Courtesy [was] extended" - how does adding or removing "was" affect the meaning?

Tags: grammar

> The meeting was not an obligation, but a courtesy *extended* by both parties.

Is this sentence correct?
I think "was extended.." in place of "extended" will fit.

Comment: You could insert "that was" to maintain the sense of the original (the meeting _was_ the courtesy), but inserting "was" alone conveys something completely different (the courtesy can now refer to something other than the meeting).

Comment: I've edited your question's title to make it more descriptive. Please feel free to roll back the edit or change it further if it isn't suitable.

Answer (score 1):

This is an example of a form of ellipsis called [whiz-deletion](https://english.stackexchange.com/tags/whiz-deletion/info#:%7E:text=Whiz%2Ddeletion%20is%20a%20type,be%20from%20certain%20relative%2Dclauses.&text=The%20term%20is%20a%20humorous,%2C%20hence%20wh%20%2B%20is%20deletion.), where a relative pronoun and a be-verb are omitted from a sentence. The sentence without ellipsis would be:

> The meeting was not an obligation, but a courtesy [that was] extended by both parties

Answer (score 0):

There **extended** is the past participle used adjectivally as a postmodifier of **courtesy** and so no verb is needed.  The structure is :  not an X but a Y.

> It was not a command but merely a suggestion offered.
>
> The passport was not authentic but someone else's passport altered.

If you want to use a verb such that you'd have two clauses, it would be better to use the past perfect if describing the events that *had led* to the meeting:

> The meeting was not an obligation but a courtesy had been extended.

But if you are describing the events  *as they were unfolding*, then you could use **was**:

> The meeting was not an obligation but a courtesy was extended.